# PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues in a PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a PreferenceFragment and I want to set the default values according to an XML file. Here is my onCreate method:

```
 public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
 ...

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // Load the preferences from an XML resource
   addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

   //This is the faulty line
   PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true);
 }
```

Unfortunately, it does not compile because "this" is not a proper context.

How should this be done?

Comment: You want to save the activity? What would you want to use that for?

Comment: I'm saving the settings of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the first parameter of `setDefaultValues` is a `Context`. A `PreferenceFragment` is not a `Context` so use this.

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.xml.preferences, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use getActivity() as you are in a fragment, not a Context.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `getActivity()` to get a `Context` inside a `Fragment`. Note that you can only use this Method safely after `onActivityCreated(Bundle)` was called by the system.
So you might want to use something like the following:

```
 public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
   ...
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     // Load the preferences from an XML resource
     addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

     //This was the faulty line
     PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.xml.preferences, true);
   }
 }
```